# Multiple instances of xelatex in parallel without overwriting generated PDF's

Tags: xetex, pdf, datatool, csv

I've one TeX file `abc.tex`
which is executed using `xelatex abc.tex` to generate the PDF file `abc.pdf`

Inside `abc.tex` I'm using the `datatool` package to read data from an external CSV file (say `pqr.csv`).

Now, I've to execute multiple CSV files for which I need to generate a PDF using `abc.tex`.

Currently, I'm manually changing the name of the CSV file inside `abc.tex` and executing `xelatex` to generate the PDF.

Is there any smart option to perform same operation multiple times? 
Is there any way I can run four instances of `xelatex abc.tex` and generate four separate PDF files in parallel?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can first of all use a macro to hold the name of the `.csv` file in `abc.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}

\begin{document}

...

\DTLloaddb[noheader,keys={Temperature,Time,T2G}]{data}{\csvname.csv}

...

\end{document}
```

Then you can call `xelatex` from the command line by saying

```
xelatex -jobname=abc-pqr '\def\csvname{pqr}\input{abc}'

xelatex -jobname=abc-stu '\def\csvname{stu}\input{abc}'

xelatex -jobname=abc-vwx '\def\csvname{wvx}\input{abc}'
```

The first line will read `pqr.csv` and produce a file `abc-pqr.pdf`, the second line will read `stu.csv` and produce `abc-stu.pdf`, and similarly for the third line.

Comment: Thanks a lot egreg for giving PERFECT direction. This is VERY MUCH useful.